# Merge rows with same color but different value

Tags: microsoft-excel

Let's say I have 4 rows in 2 columns as below

```
      | Col 1 | Col 2 |
Row 1 | Blue  |  54   |
Row 2 | Blue  |  25   |
Row 3 | Red   |  21   |
Row 4 | Blue  |  65   |
```

What I want is for Excel to recognise the two columns as one. So I want Excel to give one output, which would be the following three columns

```
      | Col 1 | Col 2 | Col 3 |
Row 1 | Blue  |  3    |  144  |
Row 2 | Red   |  1    |  21   |
```

Where the first column should be the 'Variable'. The second column should be the number of times it is present. The third column should give the sum of the numbers next to the variable. I will be updating the data, so the formula should also work for new data.

**So Far**

So far I have been able to solve the issue with the first two columns. The first column is simply the variable so that I can write in. The second one I have done using the `COUNTIF` command. But the third one is where I am stuck?

How can I make Excel recognise that each row has a given value?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Following method will fix the issue:**

[image]

- Enter this Array Formula in Cell `D32`, finish with **Ctrl+Shift+Enter** & fill down.

  `{=IFERROR(INDEX($A$32:$A$35,MATCH(0,COUNTIF($D$31:D31,$A$32:$A$35),0)),"")}`
- Formula in Cell `E32`:

  `=IF(COUNTIF($A$32:$A$35,$D32)=0,"",COUNTIF($A$32:$A$35,$D32))`
- Final Formula in Cell `F32`:

`=IF(SUMIF($A$32:$A$35,D32,$B$32:$B$35)=0,"",SUMIF($A$32:$A$35,D32,$B$32:$B$35))`

**N.B.**

Last 2 Formula have been wrapped with **If** to replace `Zero` with `Blanks` when not get values in successive rows.

*Adjust cell references in the Formula as needed.*

Comment: Thanks a bunch for the help!

Comment: Glad to help you @MathCurious314,, keep asking ☺

Comment: @MathCurious314,, why after long time you have rejected my post as answer,, any issue ?

Comment: ah my bad. I accepted your answer, but also clicked on green tick on the other one today. I mistook the green tick for something else. But now I know. Still getting used to how to work on this site.

Comment: @MathCurious314,, it's okay no problem,, keep asking ☺

Answer (score 1):

You can use **SUMPRODUCT** function to get the result.

For Count column:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(($A$1:$A$4=D1)*1)
```

[image]

For Sum column:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(($A$1:$A$4=D1)*$B$1:$B$4)
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer! It really helped me alot.